# conditional statements for raster in R - land surface temperature

Tags: r, landsat-8, digital-image-processing, if-else

Im trying to calculate Land surface temperature estimating with Landsat 8 images, but i got stuck in one place and i cant move on. I m following split window algorithm.
 I calculated NDVI  and I have to apply criteria to calculate land surface emmisivity. here my script in R studio :

```
#Ndvi
NDVI=(Palfa.B5-Palfa.B4)/(Palfa.B4+Palfa.B5)
NDVI <- NDVI@data@values
#vegetation fraction
NDVImin=0.2 #pre set value
NDVImax=0.5 #pre set value
Pv <- ((NDVI-NDVImin)/(NDVImax-NDVImin))^2
#roughness of the surface
F=0.55 #pre set value of geometric factor
C10 <- (1-es10) * ev10 * (1-Pv) * F
C11 <- (1-es11) * ev11 * (1-Pv) * F
#LSE for band 10
e10 <- if (NDVI<=0.2) {-0.047 * Palfa.B4+0.973} 
       else if (NDVI>0.2 && NDVI<=0.5) {ev10 * Pv+es10 * (1-Pv)+C10} 
       else (NDVI>0.5) ev10+C10

#LSE for band 11
e11 <- if (NDVI<=0.2) { -0.026 * Palfa.B5+0.984 } 
       else if (NDVI>0.2 && NDVI<=0.5) { ev11 * Pv+es11 * (1-Pv)+C11 }
       else (NDVI>0.5) ev11+C11
```

something is wrong bcs i got this :

> Warning message: In if (NDVI <= 0.2) { :   the condition has length >
>   1 and only the first element will be used ev11+C11

I also tried with ifelse but then my result is vector but i need to export raster 
have u got any ideas how can i solve it?
Attached  you will find criteria : 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are ev10, es10, ev11 and es11 constants or rasters?

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen ev10,es10,ev11 es111 are constants but Pv and C10 and C11 are rasters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not notice in my initial answer that NDVI was a vector created from the values of a raster. That is why you are receiving that warning message. It will not evaluate the condition for more than one element. Since you need to evaluate an entire raster and use other rasters in the calculations you can use the method shown here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/167514/70980

```
library(raster)
#Create sample rasters
NDVI <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5)
NDVI <- setValues(NDVI, runif(ncell(NDVI)))
Pv <- setValues(NDVI, runif(25 ,0.6,0.9))
Palfa.B4 <- setValues(NDVI, runif(25 ,0.2,0.4))
C10 <- setValues(NDVI, runif(25 ,1,2))

#Stack rasters 
s <- stack(NDVI, Pv, Palfa.B4, C10)
#Sample values for constants
es10 <- 0.85
ev10 <- 0.54

#if-else reclassify statement
rc <- function(x1,x2,x3,x4) {
  #x1 - NDVI
  #x2 - Pv
  #x3 - Palfa.B4
  #x4 - C10
  ifelse(x1 <= 0.2, (-0.047 * x3 + 0.973), 
         ifelse((x1 > 0.2) & (x1 <= 0.5), (ev10 * x2 + es10 * (1 - x2) + x4), 
                ev10 + x4))
}

r.class <- overlay(s, fun=rc)
```